# writing procedure output to file with column header

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "exec "'+@dbname+'"..myproc" queryout "'+@filepath+'text1.txt" -c -t "|" -r \n -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I'm using above query to write `myproc` procedure output to pipeline delimited text file. It is working fine except output file doesn't have column header.

How to add column header without making any change inside procedure code.

Comment: You can't do that with BCP. You have to manually add the header with another select (ie `SELECT "head1", "head2" UNION SELECT yourquery` )

Comment: you mean `SELECT "ID","NAME"
UNION
SELECT * FROM TEST`. But it is not working

Comment: why its not working ? both `select` should have the same number of fields and it should work.

Comment: I got error Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ID' to data type int. It has only 2 columns.

Comment: `SELECT "ID","NAME" UNION SELECT CAST(ID as VARCHAR), NAME FROM TEST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
-- Create Temp Table 
CREATE TABLE #TMP_TABLE(COL1 varchar(50), COL2 varchar(50), COL3 varchar(100));

-- Insert Stored Proc Data in Temp Table
INSERT INTO #TMP_TABLE
EXEC dbo.myproc;

-- Select Column name + Date (Use ' not " for String delimiter)
SELECT 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #TMP_TABLE;
```